# Example for ReactPropGroup

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ui-components

I'm implementing a new native UI component for my project. For some reason, I need to set 2 properties at the same time using one method. By using `ReactProp` I can set only one property like this:

```
@ReactProp(name = "mode")
public void setMode(PDFLayoutView view, int mode) {
    view.PDFSetView(mode);
}
```

But if I want to set for example `src` and `password` properties I can't use `ReactProp` annotation.

```
@ReactProp(name = "src")
public void setMode(PDFLayoutView view, string src, string password) {
    view.setSrc(src, password);
}
```

I checked https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android#imageview-example and found `ReactPropGroup` annotation might help me. But there is no example of how to use it. Can you provide an example or another solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of using ReactPropGroup.

```java
@ReactPropGroup(names = {"src","password"})
public void setMode(PDFLayoutView view, string src, string password) {
    view.setMode(src, password);
}
```

Example of using conditional statements for parameters

```java
@ReactPropGroup(names = {
    ViewProps.BORDER_RADIUS,
    ViewProps.BORDER_TOP_LEFT_RADIUS,
    ViewProps.BORDER_TOP_RIGHT_RADIUS,
    ViewProps.BORDER_BOTTOM_RIGHT_RADIUS,
    ViewProps.BORDER_BOTTOM_LEFT_RADIUS
}, defaultFloat = YogaConstants.UNDEFINED)
public void setBorderRadius(ReactEditText view, int index, float borderRadius) {
  if (!YogaConstants.isUndefined(borderRadius)) {
    borderRadius = PixelUtil.toPixelFromDIP(borderRadius);
  }

  if (index == 0) {
    view.setBorderRadius(borderRadius);
  } else {
    view.setBorderRadius(borderRadius, index - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me how can I use these props is JS?

Comment: Please refer https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android

Comment: it can't be found

Comment: The first example, "public void setMode(PDFLayoutView view, string src, string password) {", does not work for me, since the function should receive an index and a value, not a value in each param.

Comment: Today, the doc is available in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/annotations/ReactPropGroup.java (as comment)